# Insert Html tag inside a DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I insert a html tag like `<p>` to enclose the "Search" text.

```
<button id="ihf-quicksearch-submit2" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary btn-form-submit ihf-main-search-form-submit" type="submit"> Search </button>
```

Because I want to hide that "Search" text when the page width is equal =< 900.
So that it will be change to a magnifying glass glyph icon.

I have tried jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
var windowsize = jQuery(window).width();

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  windowsize = jQuery(window).width();
  if (windowsize < 900) {
    jQuery('#ihf-quicksearch-submit2').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search fa fa-search"></i>');
  } if (windowsize >900) {
    jQuery('#ihf-quicksearch-submit2').html(' Search ');
}
});
});
</script>
```

jQuery worked for changing the "Search" to magnifying glass icon. BUT when page is still loading it still shows the "Search" text. And it doesn't look good on mobile version.

So I want to have a "HTML tag" before the "Search" so I can "display:none;" it from CSS using @media CSS.

> **NOTE:** I can't insert `<p>` manually cause I cant locate the code from the plugin that I am using.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Very simple - get the HTML of the button by ID, then modify it as a string, and store it back in the button's HTML.

```
var innerHTML = $('#ihf-quicksearch-submit2').html();
innerHTML = '<p>' + innerHTML + '</p>';
$('#ihf-quicksearch-submit2').html(innerHTML);
```

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cccd2yuz/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!
I solved my problem now, 

I combined your answer with "Jeff Puckett II". 
You guys rock! :)

Comment: @MarkLozano Not a problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You could just stick them both in there and hide them based on a media query:

```html
<script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button id="ihf-quicksearch-submit2" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary btn-form-submit ihf-main-search-form-submit" type="submit"> Search </button>

<style>
@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
   .search-text {
  display: none;
   }
   #ihf-quicksearch-submit2 {
  opacity: 0;
   }
}
@media screen and (min-width:900px) {
   .search-icon {
  display: none;
   }
}
</style>

<script>
$("#ihf-quicksearch-submit2").html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search fa fa-search search-icon"></i><span class="search-text">Search</span>').css( "opacity", "1" );
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I already thought of that and I would like to do that,
But I cant find the specific line of code on the plugin.
That is why I cannot add any HTML tags/class that i can call on css.

That is why I want the "Search" text to be wrapped around with "< p>" or "< span>"

Comment: I've updated my answer, just find the element and replace its contents.

Comment: I made one more update after thinking about your waiting for page load until jQuery fires: You could hide the text with opacity, and then reset it with the jQuery when it loads.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!
I solved my problem now, though I still needed to add the answer of "Tricky12".

I combined your answers. You guys rock! :)

Answer (score 0):

So Here is the answer to my question. Just in case there is anyone out there that is having a problem same as mine. I combined the answers of "Tricky12" and  "Jeff Puckett II" - credits to them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    var innerHTML = jQuery('#ihf-quicksearch-submit2').html();
    innerHTML = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search fa fa-search search-icon"></i><span class="search-text">' + innerHTML + '</span>';
    jQuery('#ihf-quicksearch-submit2').html(innerHTML);
});
</script>


<style>
@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
.search-text {
display: none;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width:900px) {
.search-icon {
display: none;
}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is other child to this div and you dont need to wipe them all you can use this method in javascipt

JavaScript

```
var CodeInsideDiv = document.getElementById("samplediv")
var injection = "<p>sample text</p>"
CodeInsideDiv.innerHTML = injection + CodeInsideDiv.innerHTML
```

In HTML this happens

```
<div id="samplediv">

<p>sample text<p> #<<<--Magic inserted this  here#

<p>SAMPLE TEXT</p>
<div id="nested-div">....</div>   
</div>
```